# .htaccess get variable through url rewrite not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a script inside of my `.htaccess` file in which I am attempting to change the url from `localhost/testing/user/index?username=example` to `localhost/testing/user/example`.

I am doing this just to make my website look "cleaner" and easier to navigate around users.

This is my current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ user/index?username=$1;
RewriteRule ^user/$ user/index;
```

For some reason this doesn't want to work for me and ALWAYS throws either a **404** or **500** error.

This is the PHP code in which I am using to get the username passed through the URL.

```
if(isset($_GET['username']) && empty($_GET['username'])){
        header('location: ./');
    }

    if(empty($_GET['username']) && logged_in() == false){
        header('location: ./');
    } else if(empty($_GET['username']) && logged_in() == true || isset($_GET['username']) && $_GET['username'] === $username){
        $pageDisp = 1;
    } else if(!empty($_GET['username']) && $_GET['username'] !== $username){
        $pageDisp = 2;
}
```

In the PHP, if `$_GET['username']` is empty, it will just set the user to the logged in user, but if they are logged in, it will redirect them to a 404.

This is the layout of my folders and scripts:

**.htaccess** : /testing/user/

**user index.php** : /testing/user/

**main index.php** : /testing/

ALl of these files are located inside of my XAMPP htdocs folder.

All help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: do you want to remove `.php` extension?

Comment: @thewbmstr nope. already done that in my root `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me

Match anything after the `/testing/user/*`

HTACCESS

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^testing/users/([^/]*)$ /testing/users/?username=$1 [L]
```

index.php inside the `/testing/users/` (test)

```
<?php echo $_GET['username'] ?>
```

Comment: now it is just redirecting me to `localhost/testing/user/?username=example` rather than just keeping it as `localhost/testing/user/example` :/